# Periodic points of topologically conjugated functions in dynamical systems?

Tags: functions, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I'm working on a homework problem which seems obvious, but I am having a hard time proving/completing. The problem can be stated as follows:

Let $f,g:$ $\mathbb R$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal C^1$ functions and suppose they are topologically conjugated by a diffeomorphism $h$. Let $x_0$ be a periodic point of period $n$ of $f$. Prove that $y_0=h(x_0)$ is a periodic point of period $n$ of $g$, and that $(f^n)'(x_0)=(g^n)'(h(x_0))$

The first part seems pretty obvious from the definition of topological conjugacy - it preserves all the dynamics, so the periodic point is preserved as well. Anything beyond this seems to be lost on me, and I can't figure out how to start the second part.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have $h(f^n) = g^n(h)$, just differentiate and use the chain rule:
$$(h(f^n))' = (g^n(h))'$$
$$h'(f^n)\cdot(f^n)' = (g^n)'(h)\cdot h'$$
Evaluating at $x_0$, and recalling that $f^n(x_0)=x_0$ and $g^n(h(x_0))=h(x_0)$,
$$h'(\;\underbrace{f^n(x_0)}_{x_0}\;)\cdot(f^n)'(x_0) = (g^n)'(h(x_0))\cdot h'(x_0)$$
$$\require{cancel}\cancel{h'(x_0)}\cdot(f^n)'(x_0) = (g^n)'(h(x_0))\cdot \cancel{h'(x_0)}$$
Cancelling $h'(x_0)$ (since it isn't zero),
$$\boxed{(f^n)'(x_0) = (g^n)'(h(x_0))}$$
as desired.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know you could make that first claim about conjugates. I thought the conjugacy only applied to the functions, not their iterates. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Well, you have to prove to yourself that it's true. You can write (abbreviating composition) $f = h^{-1}gh$, so just note that $f^n = (h^{-1}gh)(h^{-1}gh)\cdots(h^{-1}gh)$ and all of the "interior" $h^{-1}h$ are identity, leaving $f^n = h^{-1}g^nh$. This gives what you want, right?

Comment: No of course this is true. As soon as you wrote it, it hit me.